# When using onChange with React, spaces are not registered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onchange

I am trying to save a user's input by using the onChange method described here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html.

I have this line of code for my input:

```
      <input type="text" onChange={this.changeTitle} ref="title" value={this.props.quiz ? this.getTitle() : ''}></input>
```

However, when I call `this.refs.title.value` after pressing the spacebar, the space is not registered.  Is there anyway I can register this space?

Comment: The input should register the space/ should fire `this.changeTitle` if you press space. Hard to tell what happens without further code. In any case, it would be cleaner to put the value of the input in some state, and replace `value={this.props.quiz ? this.getTitle() : ''}` with something like `value={this.state.value}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something as

```
var ChangeValue = React.createClass({

    getInitialState() {
      return { currentValue: '' };
    },

    onValueChange: function (evnt) {
      this.setState({ currentValue: evnt.target.value });
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
          <div>
             <input type="text" onChange={this.onValueChange} />
             <p>
               Current value is: <b>{this.state.currentValue}</b>
             </p>
          </div>
        );
    }
});

React.render(<ChangeValue />, document.body);
```

Just change onValueChange method to do what you need.
Live example: http://jsbin.com/xayowaloxa/edit?html,js,output